# Can JavaScript String Function charAt() look for multiple characters?

Tags: javascript, netbeans, string-function

How can I make my string.charAt() look for multiple characters at once? I'm looking to reduce the lines of code I have in my program, just wondering how I can fit multiple characters into one line.

Example: normally I would type

```
(string.charAt(4));
```

if i wanted to find the character at spot 4, what if I wanted to find the character at spots 3-5? would i write

```
(string.charAt(3-5));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Q: Can string.charAt() look for multiple characters at once?  A: No.  String.charAt() doesn't "look at" *ANY* "characters".  It turns *THE* character at *THE SPECIFIED* "index".  Q: Could you show us an example string, what describe what you'd like to "look for"?  I suspect maybe you can use a [regex](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/index.html)

Comment: the java language does not have a charAt method for the string class

Comment: Riley, you may want to edit your title to reflect "Javascript" as opposed to "Java". Both exist and differ quite a bit. The charAt() method belongs to Javascript.

And I second @paulsm4 request to show us an example. This will help you find your answer.

Comment: Why not `string[i]`, where `i` is the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use slice() method if you want to get a portion of a string:

```js
let string = 'Hello World'
console.log(string.slice(2, 6));
```

If you need to get only the letters in specific indexes you can do this:

```js
function getLetters(str, ...args){
    let result = '';
    for(let index in str){
        result += str.charAt(args[index]);
    }
    return result
}

let indexes = [2, 5, 6, 8, 9];
console.log(getLetters(string, ...indexes));
```